# What to substitute in any given integral?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, substitution

I've been given a problem by my math lecturer to think about:
Use substitution to find the exact value of: $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-25x^4}}dx$
 How do you figure out what the value of $u$ should be for the substitution? Ive tried $u=5x$ but this doesn't work. 
 Is there a way I can generally work out what $u$ should be for any given integral?

Comment: There is no general method to work out the substitution $u$. You have to check for yourself which substitution suits your integral the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $u=5x^2$ so $\frac{du}{dx}=10x$. Then the integral becomes
$$\frac1{10}\int_0^{1/2}\frac 1{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
which should be easy to solve. It should help noticing that integrands of the form $\frac?{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ are usually easy to solve, and that $25x^4=(5x^2)^2$.

Comment: Do you mean that $25x^4 = (5x^2)^2$? And in terms of the limits, how do you work them out?

Comment: @OliverDransfield You just say "$x$ goes from $0$ to $1/\sqrt{10}$, so $u=5x^2$ goes from $0$ to $1/2$. And yes, that is a typo.